# Decrease the execution time of a sequential procedure in R

Tags: r, string, performance, parallel-processing

Bellow I posted three functions that i wrote to calculate and produce a grid with all possible combinations between the positions of different letters in words. Let me give you an example and then see the actual code.

E.g

let be a phrase equal to "Today is a perfect day" and imagine that we have a list (phrase1) of all of its words. `phrase1 = list("Today", "is", "a", "perfect", "day")`

This variable (phrase1) is part of a bigger list that contains more phrases. `phrases = list( phrase1=list(), phrase2=list() ...)`

Now for each word of each phrase I want to find all the possible combinations between the specified letters.

At the beginning I supplement my functions with a character list with the target characters , a category list  and a phrases list.

`char_list = c("o","a")
cat_list = c("cat1", "cat2")`

`cat1` always corresponds to letter "o" and `cat2` to letter "a" respectively.

If this is the case then, for the word "Today" of the first phrase (phrase1), I'm getting the following table

```
 word   | cat1 | cat2 
 -------|----- |-----
  p1w1  |  2   |  0   
  p1w1  |  0   |  0   
  p1w1  |  0   |  4   
  p1w1  |  2   |  4
```

EDIT: So here is the table for the first word (w1) of the first phrase (p1) with all possible combinations between the positions of the two letters specified earlier.

while for the whole list of phrases this grid look like :

```
 word   | cat1  | cat2 
 -------|------ |-----
  p1w1  |  ..   |  ..   
  p1w1  |  ..   |  ..   
  p1w2  |  ..   |  ..   
  p1w2  |  ..   |  ..   
  p2w1  |  ..   |  ..   
  p2w1  |  ..   |  ..  
  ...
```

EDIT: The final table of the whole process is the table that contains all possible combinations between the positions of the specified letter of all words of all phrases.

Now the thing is that if my initial list is big enough (4096 phrases with hundreds of words each one) then this procedure is taking a big amount of time until completion because it reads each word after the other and so on just sequentially.

For example I'm running my script on windows server with 25 cores and 32GB ram and only uses 5-10% of one core and takes about 4 hours.

I start reading about parallel computation in R but though to ask here for that specific approach and see if there is any other good idea in order to increase the performance.

I would like also to mention that I'm not a professional R coder and many performance mistakes could be found.

Thank you.

Function area :

I'm just calling the `all.combs.grid(char_list, cat_list, phrases_list)`

```
all.combs.grid = function(char_list , cat_list , phrases_list){

  mod_words = matrix()

  final.grid = matrix(ncol = 2+length(cat_list))
  colnames(final.grid) = c("phrase", "sequence" , cat_list)

  i = 1

  for(phrase in phrases_list){

    # Get phrase ID
    phrase_id = names(phrases_list)[i]

    # Get word after word for each phrase
    for(d in 1:length(phrase[[1]])){
      # word sequence
      word = phrase[[1]][d]

      # get the matrix of all possible combinations for that word
      word_pos_combs = all.combs.word.grid(char_list , cat_list, word)


      # number of combinations
      no_of_comb = nrow(word_pos_combs)
      # Create a phrase id and word vector
      phrase_tag = rep(phrase_id, no_of_comb)
      word_tag = rep(word, no_of_comb)

      # Combine phrase_tag , word_tag and word_pos_combs
      mod_words = cbind(phrase_tag , word_tag, word_pos_combs)

      # Combine mod_words variable for all words in a phrase into a matrix
      # one under the other
      final.grid = rbind(final.grid, mod_words)

    } # word loop    
  }

  # Remove the first row which has NAs
  final.grid = na.omit(final.grid)
  # Set proper row names.
  row.names(final.grid) = 1:nrow(final.grid)

  write.csv(x = final.grid , file = combs, row.names = F)

}

all.combs.word.grid = function(char_list , cat_list , word ){

  comb_list = list()

  for( i in seq_along(char_list) ){

      char = char_list[i]
      char_combs = char.combs( word, char )
      comb_list = c( comb_list, list( char_combs ) )

      if(a.a == "0" && length(a.a) == 1) # If there is no instance of the target a.a in the peptide
        return("0")     
    }
  }

  # Generate the matrix of the unique instances for each category.
  # e.g
  #      cat1     cat2    cat3
  # [1,] "1"      "0"      "0"      
  # [2,] "3"      "0"      "0"      
  # [3,] "6"      "0"      "0"      
  # [4,] "1:3"    "0"      "0"      
  # [5,] "1:6"    "0"      "0"      
  # [6,] "3:6"    "0"      "0"      
  # [7,] "1:3:6"  "0"      "0"      
  # [8,] "0"      "2"      "0"      
  # [9,] "0"      "9"      "0"      
  # [10,] "0"     "2:9"    "0"      
  # [11,] "0"     "0"      "8"      

  m1 = create_mat(comb_list)

  # Get all the possible combinations between the above categories
  m1 = as.list(data.frame(m1))
  m1 = expand.grid(lapply(m1,unique))
  colnames(m1) = cat_list

  # Get all the possible combinations of the rest (comb_list)
  exp = expand.grid(comb_list)
  colnames(exp) = cat_list

  # Combine the two matrices
  result = rbind(m1,exp)

  result = unique(result)

  return(result)
}

char.combs = function(word , char ){

  # GET ALL INDICES of INSTANCES
  pos = unlist(gregexpr(char, word ))
  char = c()

  # If there is only one instance of the target char
  if( length(pos) == 1 && pos != -1 ){

    char = c(char , as.character(pos))
    return(char)

  # If there is no instance of the target char
  }else if ( pos == -1 || length(pos) == 1 ) {

    char = "0"
    return(char)

  # if there are more than one instances of the target char
  }else{

    for( i in 1:length(pos) ){
        comb = t(combn(pos,i))
        for( y in 1:nrow(comb)){
          comb_n = as.character(comb[y,])
          comb_n = paste(comb_n, collapse = ":")
          char = c(char , comb_n)
        }
    }

    return(char)
  } # else

}
```

Comment: Could you explain the table after `If this is the case then, for the word "Today" of the first phrase (phrase1), I'm getting the following table`?

Comment: @F.Privé I added some edits. Is it more clear now or not ?

Comment: So basically, O is in position 2 in "today" and A is in position 4. But why adding position 0 in the possibilities?

Comment: ok. Think it as this. Which are the possible combinations of the word "today" including or not the specified letters. In that way we will have `tdy , tody , tday, today`. I'm not adding anything I'm just creating all the possible combinations of the positions of these letters.

Comment: If you are working with a Windows Server you could use Microsoft R Open (MRAN) instead of base R. MRAN will automatically initiate multi-core processing. Additionally, I would check if you can transform the for-loops into apply statements since for-loops are relatively slow in R. See also "R inferno" by Patrick Burns to get an idea on how to increase your code performance (http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf)

Comment: @jd1338 if this answer helped, please consider selecting it as an answer by clicking on the check mark. This lets community know the answer worked and the issue is closed.

Comment: @CPak I would have marked your answer if I would have asked the question.

Comment: @jd1338 Haha, sorry about that. I saw the `J` and `D` and got confused I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variables you start with

```
phrase1 = list("Today", "is", "a", "perfect", "day")
phrases = list( phrase1, phrase1 )
char_list = c("o","a")
```

The following solution requires the following libraries

```
library(stringr)          # str_locate
library(purrr)            # map2
```

I made a function that acts on a single phrase

```
parsephrase <- function(phrase, z) {
                  intermediate1 <- lapply(phrase1, function(x) sapply(char_list, function(y) str_locate(x,y)[1,1]))
                  intermediate2 <- map2(intermediate1, 1:length(intermediate1), ~expand.grid(c(0,.x[1]),c(0,.x[2])) %>% filter(complete.cases(.)) %>% mutate(ID=paste0("p", z, "w",.y)))
                  intermediate3 <- Reduce("rbind", intermediate2)
                  return(intermediate3)
               }
```

Here's the output using only `phrase1`  (`head`)

```
   Var1 Var2   ID
1     0    0 p1w1
2     2    0 p1w1
3     0    4 p1w1
4     2    4 p1w1
5     0    0 p1w2
```

To operate on `phrases` use

```
final <- Reduce("rbind", map2(phrases, 1:length(phrases), ~ parsephrase(.x, .y)))
```